# High Order Function for processing results in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I've been trying to play with several ways to achieve the behavior below

Kotlin playground: https://pl.kotl.in/R_QifvkZE

```
/**
 * You can edit, run, and share this code.
 * play.kotlinlang.org
 */
fun main() {
    println(job())  
}

fun job() : String = metrics {
    println("entering metrics funciton")
    return "My String"
}

inline fun metrics(block: () -> String): String {
   val result = block()
   println("Adding some metrics about result: $result")
   return result
}
```

Basically I want to add this metrics function which will add some logs based of the result of a lambda. The console statements I would like to see are as follows

```
entering metrics function
Adding some metrics about result: My String
My String
```

But what I get from the code above actually is

```
entering metrics function
My String
```

Which makes sense, because inlining must be traducing to something similar to

```
fun job() : String {
    println("entering metrics funciton")
    return "My String"
    // unreachable code
    println("Adding some metrics about result: $result")
    return result
}
```

Now, I could solve this with labeled returns `return@metrics`. But it is not as clean, therefore my question is. Does anyone have an idea to keep similar semantics?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `return@metrics`. It's convention to not use any `return` keyword to return something from a lambda that doesn't branch into multiple possible returns. You can just put

```
fun job() : String = metrics {
    println("entering metrics funciton")
    "My String"
}
```

But there is nothing "unclean" about `return@metrics`. That's, clear explicit code. In this case it's generally better to follow convention though.